# Problem with Distributed Transactions between machines in different domains

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server, firewall, msdtc

We are tring to use an application that uses transactions.

- The machine running the code is on a stand alone Windows 2003 Server machine.
- The database server is a Windows 2003 Server with SQL Server 2005 on a domain machine on a different network.

It works when we install the application on a machine in the same domain.

I have tried going into the Component Services and marking "Allow Inbound Connections" and "No Authentication Required".

I can see that the transaction appears in the MSDTC list on both computers, but the transaction gets aborted.

Any Ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: Do you receive any sort of an error message from SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how MSDTC handles this but you could try using passthrough authentication. Set up a local user\password on the application server that matches either a local user\password on the SQL server or a domain user\password in the SQL server's domain. Configure the application to run under this user's context and see what happens.